# Definite Article before "Internet"

Tags: definite-articles

I know the definite article is frequently used before word Internet in most of cases like

> Free use of the Internet.

However, I found when it is used with other nouns, lets just say Wifi, it will drop off the definite article.

> Free use of Internet and Wifi

Comment: The definite article was needed (mandatory) in the early years. Now the Internet is so pervasive, people use it so often, it's a pain to have *the* before it every time. *Internet* by itself is considered enough and acceptable now, just take care to capitalize.

Comment: @Kris If so, why do we still continue to use "the" before "sun", "moon", "earth" even "U.S."?

Comment: "The Internet" is used because there is only one.  "Free use of Internet" is short for "Free use of Internet access"  or something similar.  The point being that Internet is a noun in one context and an adjective in the other.  We would say "Free use of the Internet" to indicate the concrete internet.

Comment: That has been answered on this site. Just search though older posts. Good Luck.

Comment: @ShpielMeister If indeed "Free use of Internet" is short for "Free use of Internet access", wouldn't using both "use" and "access" be redundant? I'd say, either "Free Internet use" or "Free Internet access".

Comment: @Kris If your last comment is directed to me, my question in the earlier comment was a rhetorical question.

Comment: @JK2. The word access is just one of several possibilities.  My point is that Internet is used as an adjective.  How about "Free Internet"?  It is clearly different from "Free the Internet".  Another possibility is to consider Internet in the category of mass nouns such as food.  "Free food" vs "Take the food"

Comment: Thank you so much! All of your comments were really helpful!

Comment: It's headlinese. 'Customers have free use of the car park.' will be shortened to 'Free use of car park' or similar.